# Вывести результаты объединения множества таблиц

Tags: java, mysql

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
user_id | name

1 name1
2 name2
3 name3
4 name4

user_id_who | user_id_whom | value

1 2 value1
2 3 value2
4 1 value3
3 2 value4
```

Каким запросом их объединить для получения результата:

```
name1 name2 value1
name2 name3 value2
name4 name1 value3
name3 name2 value4
```

Как вариант, работает объединение по одному столбцу:

```sql
SELECT NAME, VALUE 
FROM rating 
INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id=rating.user_id_who
```

Но требуется сразу по двум и более столбцам.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT u1.name AS name1, u2.name AS name2, r.value AS value
FROM rating AS r
   LEFT JOIN users AS u1 ON (r.user_id_who=u1.user_id)
   LEFT JOIN users AS u2 ON (r.user_id_whom=u2.user_id)
```

> но требуется сразу по двум и более столбцам

Более 2 столбцов я тут пока не вижу.